# If any difference between php call

Tags: php

If any difference  between `<?php content1() & content2() ?>` and `<?php content1()?><?php content2() ?>`
in my project i got some issues in this type!, So if any problem call php in those type?

Comment: what is content1 and content2 (also in first u spell contect ;) )

Comment: Can you please be more clear as of what your problem is? Your language structure is very unclear and confusing.

Comment: It's completely unclear up to what point this is pseudocode and what is real code. This *may* be actual code doing nothing in both cases, or it may be entirely nonsensical pseudocode.

Comment: Why would you even try to compare using the *bitwise AND operator* to having two separate statements in two separate PHP blocks?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a bitwise operator.

```
var_dump(1 & 0); // 0
var_dump(1 & 1); // 1
var_dump(0 & 1); // 0
var_dump(0 & 0); // 0
```

When you use a `&&` it's a logical operator:

```
var_dump(true && false); // false
var_dump(true && true); // true
var_dump(false && true); // false
var_dump(false && false); // false
```

Read the [relevant docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to learn more.

`<?=$a?><?=$b?>` would be the same as `<?=$a.$b?>` (concatenation), not `<?=$a&$b?>` (bitwise operation).

Comment: You know, I honestly think he's not going into that level of depth... I think he simply wants to know if there's any difference between putting a load of PHP inside one `<?php ... ?>` block and several `<?php ... ?>` blocks in the same script :) Granted the OP is only marginally more transparent than a house-brick so I could well be wrong.

Comment: Probably true, but I'm here to educate everyone who might stumble into this in the future :)

Comment: That was my assumption. Given the typos, I assumed by &, && was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean && not the bitwise operator &, and if those are method names, and you've got method 1 content1() and method 2 content2(), then there is a huge difference between

```
<?php content1(); ?><?php content2(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php content1() && content2(); ?>
```

In the first example, it'll simply run one, then the other. Whereas in the second example, content2() will only be run if content1() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the result of the bit-wise operator between the results of the two function calls and the second consists of two function calls in separate statements.